# Aplicação enviado duas vezes a mesma mensagem

Tags: c#, winforms, skype

Estou  com um novo problema com a biblioteca do skype `(skype4com)`. Na verdade são dois problemas. Estou fazendo minha aplicação em `WindowsForm` `(C#)`.

Fiz uma aplicação para enviar resposta automática no skype.

```
private Skype skypeId;
private string resposta = "**********ESTA E UMA RESPOSTA AUTOMATICA**********";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    //captura a instancia do skype
    skypeId = new Skype();
    skypeId.Attach(7, false);

    //Monitor
    skypeId.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(skypeId_MessageStatus);

}

public void skypeId_MessageStatus (ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
{
    if(msg.Body != "")
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        try
        {
            skypeId.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, resposta);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

O que acontece é que quando chega uma mensagem no skype a aplicação envia após 5 segundos duas vezes a mensagem `resposta`. já tentei colocar uma variável `bool` para verificar e ficou igual abaixo, mas não funcionou:

```
public void skypeId_MessageStatus (ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
{
    bool novaMsg = true;
    if(msg.Body != "" && novaMsg == true)
    {
        novaMsg = false;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        try
        {
            skypeId.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, resposta);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

Outro problema é que somente esta enviado a resposta para novas mensagens de pessoas, mensagens em grupo não é respondida. Eu já vi aqui em uma pergunta de outro usuário que a forma de resposta em chat é assim Ex.: `msg.Chat.SendMessage("Mensagem");`, porém como posso diferenciar uma conversa normal de uma chat em grupo do skype?

Comment: Um detalhe que esqueci de mencionar, ele não para de enviar a mensagem enquanto a mesma não é visualizada. Então fica enviando duas mensagem a cada 5 segundos!

Answer (score 0):

No método que responde a uma nova mensagem utilizei uma condição para responder:

```
public void skypeId_MessageStatus (IChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
if(status == TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived)
{
    skype.SendMessage(msg.FromHandle, resp);                 
}
```

Assim, quando é respondido um nova mensagem ela passa a não ser mais do tipo **Recebida** `TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived`, e ao verificar o status não entra na condição de "nova mensagem".